# Distributedfilesystem class use local instead of distributed classes

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed-filesystem

I have this line in my code:

```
DistributedFileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(new URI(otherArgs[1])), true);
```

`otherArgs[1]` has this value: `hdfs://master:54310/input/results`

I receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:hdfs://master:54310/input/results, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:55)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:367)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.delete(ChecksumFileSystem.java:430)
at <package>.<classname>.main(Degree.java:137)
```

Note: I tried to use `new Path(otherArgs[1])` without URI but got the exact same error !

Thanks,
-K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was running my jar using "hadoop -jar " instead of "hadoop jar ". All conf files are correct and in place.

Problem solved but i still have no idea why using "-jar" made it run as a local (pseudo distributed) !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not set **fs.default.name** in core-site.xml.

check this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/core-default.html)

If you have already set that, make sure the config files are in classpath

You can also set the fs.default.name property from your driver

```
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://yourserver:port");
```